# org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.1.0', apply: false] was not found

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

sorry for my bad English in advance.
I just installed android-studio and I'm getting this error

```
org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.1.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:8.1.0')
  Searched in the following repositories:
```

gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.2-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.1.0" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.8.0" apply false
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

setting.gradle

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.name = "My Application1"
include(":app")
```

already tried downloading gradle 8.1 and 8.2 by changing "distributionUrl"